# Calculated Member with a Parent member inside a ragged/parent-child dimension?

Tags: ssas, mdx, cube, dimensional-modeling

I have a ragged account hierarchy, `[Data Type].[Data Type Hierarchy]` (simple key, name, parent key table).

root

- account 1

  1. sub account 1A
  2. sub account 1B
  3. account 2 (child of Account 1)
- account 3

  1. sub account 3A

Now, I want to add the calculated member with the `[Data Type].[Data Type Hierarchy]` set as Parent Hierarchy, and `[account 2]` as the Parent member.

in the fact table there is no data for the `[account 2]`, as it is supposed to be a simple a placeholder for several calculated member.

**Problem #1:** I cant see the member when I use click on "select parent member" in BIDS. I can add it to either the [All] level, or one of the other accoutns (that has data)

**problem #2:** If I use script view, I can manually set the correct parent member, but it will not aggregate the calculated member, thus being hidden, unless "show empty cells" is checked. If I drill down, my calculated member will show, with the expected value though.